# Solve the following 6x6 grid

Tags: word

There is a 6x6 grid. Each row/column has A, B, C and D exactly once, and two blanks. Each cell may have upto one letter only. A blank is not a letter.

**Hints**

- The left-most letter of row 2 is A and right-most is B
- The left-most letter of row 3 is also A
- The right-most letter of row 4 is B
- The left-most letters of row 5 and 6 are both B
- The first letter of the first column is D
- The first letter in columns 2 and 3 is A
- Column 2 ends with D (or 1/2 spaces after a D)
- For column 4 and 6, the first letter is B and last is C

There exists a unique solution; I have twice-verified.

Please help out with the tags...

Comment: Don't the first two conditions put the letter `A` in column 1 twice? (And the same with `B` in 2, 4, 5, and 6?)

Comment: @Emrakul I think he meant it as "First letter of row..."

Comment: @Novarg Hmm... if `A` is the first letter in two rows, it seems like it'd still violate the rules of the puzzle.

Comment: @Emrakul by saying "First letter of row" I meant that there are no other letters before that, but there can be a blank

Comment: @Novarg Ahh, I see. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [image: Does this work? ;)]

Oh well, this puzzle was something else. Innovative indeed and mind-boggling! Thanks!

Comment: These puzzles are sometimes called "easy as abc" puzzles and there are a lot of them. check this image search: https://www.google.com/search?q=EASY+AS+ABC+puzzles&tbm=isch

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know those existed. +1 
Still I'd let the 'innovative' word live in my answer, assuming the OP created it. `:)`

Comment: @IvoBeckers Oh, ok. I had seen found one in a book, so I tweaked it a bit and posted it. Thanks for letting me know that others make them as well.